# Storing passwords on server

Tags: swift, xcode, encryption

I want to do the following

1. User signs up to IOS app and provides username and password
2. Make a server call and store password in server database
3. When user logs in in the future, retrieve that password and check against the password that the user entered.

How can I do this in the most secure way possible? I was thinking of encrypting the password when storing in the db. When the user logsin, use the same encryption algorithm and compare against the db encrypted password.

Comment: Encrypting the database is entirely useless for this purpose. Try to use a single-sign-on provider, like Google, Facebook, Apple, Github, etc. If you don't know the basics of password authentication, you shouldn't try it in a real environment. You're risking your users' data. I'd recommend checking out https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ZtInClXe1Q

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NEVER ever store user credentials in encrypted (reversible) form. Currently best known way for checking user credentials is slow salted hash

for what and why please read https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2013/11/20/serious-security-how-to-store-your-users-passwords-safely/

> However, don’t try to invent your own algorithm for repeated hashing. 
>   Choose one of these three well-known ones: PBKDF2, bcrypt or scrypt.

As already commented you may outsource the user authentication to some reliable service (google, fb, aws cognito, ibm appid,...)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking into databases? I know that Firebase has an authentication component of their database for ios development, and you might want to try to look into it or other databases. Check out firebase at: https://firebase.google.com/